# Which repository for recent software versions?

Tags: ubuntu, repository

I'm using Ubuntu for developement and I need to use really recent versions of gcc, mercurial and several other applications.

Is there a repository that I can set to get all my software that would be always up to date?

Some people tell me to switch to Fedora, but I don't understand exactly what will it change?

Answer (score 2):

Fedora is released every 6 months, as is Ubuntu, so it won't really make things better for you if you move to that.

Ubuntu doesn't have a "most recent" repo - there were plans for a "rolling" repository called Grumpy Groundhog, but it never happened.

You can take your packages from the current branch (e.g. maverick, at time of writing) and backport them to whatever version you are using.  You can also look for more recent packages in [backports](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports).  It's generally best to stay with packaged software unless you know what you're doing.

If you want to always be up-to-date, you could switch to Debian unstable, which is similar, but obviously not identical to, Ubuntu.  It has packages released for new things as the maintainers feel like, and because of this, it isn't always guaranteed to be compatible with itself!

Answer (score 1):

Move to rolling relase distro as Arch Linux or Gentoo to have bleeding edge software. That is easiest and most convinient way.

Answer (score 0):

Try compiling your own packages and create your own repository with your own "recent version" of every piece of software you need =).

There's no gnu linux distribution that will fullfill your needs =)

Answer (score 0):

I would install them from source. You keep the OS you are comfortable with and you get the latest updates. If the compiling of those is simple enough you could drop all the tar.gz files in one folder and just write a little script to unzip and compile them all.